# response.sendRedirect() does not running - Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, response, getattribute

When run the below code and the output I receive is "in", but the response .sendRedirect() does not run. The two  java servlet files "Class1" and "Servlet1" are in the same folder.

```
public class Class1 extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
   throws IOException, ServletException {

       response.setContentType("text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7");
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(response.getWriter(), true);

       ArrayList list2 = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list_lo");

       if (list2 == null || list2.isEmpty() ) {
          out.println("in");
          response.sendRedirect("Servlet1");
          return;}
       }


}
```

Comment: I think you have missed configuring the web.xml file for url mapping

Comment: Could you kindly post your `web.xml` excerpt where you have configured this?

Comment: You cannot send redirect once you start returning any output. I'm not sure if merely getting the writer through response.getWriter() counts, try putting the redirect logic at the very beginning of the method (that is a good thing to do anyways). And remove the `out.println("in");` as this will mean printing output for sure and thus prevent you from doing the redirect.

Comment: Yes, I have configured the web.xml

Comment: @Jiri Tousek thank you. The println was the problem.

Comment: @JiriTousek      it's not correct! You can do it, you have to make sure that you set the status code correctly too. I have this working on my system all the time, no problems.....the OPs issue is not this...

Comment: @nancy I've made it a full answer.

Comment: @ha9u63ar if we're talking about classic redirect using 302 header, it cannot be used after response body is started - see my answer for reason behind this. The only possible way it might work for you I can think of is that your started response is still in some buffer and wasn't actually sent to the client - don't rely on this!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the name of the file with the extension instead of the class name, sometimes happened to me, and just by doing this worked

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send redirect once you start returning any output.

You need to put the logic handling any possible redirects before any output is started (e.g. `out.println()` in your example). Putting the redirect logic at the very beginning of the method is a sensible thing to do anyways, since it should be the first thing you decide.

The reason why redirecting after output is started lies in the HTTP protocol itself - redirect is transmitted using response headers, which are separated from response body by a blank line. Once you start writing the response body, there's no way to transmit any more headers anymore (apart from the started output being still in buffer if you're lucky).